# Suggestions to optimise brute force number solver python

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, brute-force

I'm aware of a few other similar threads, but im not sure how to apply them to my example.

I am trying to attack the countdown number game from a brute force algorithm. This is my first attempt at anything like this, so any tips on how to speed up the process up?

I am testing it for situations where the answer is unsolvable given the initial numbers. This eventually will be paired up with a tkinter interface for the full game.

## structure should look like this, where we try every order of abcdef and every operation combo for op1-5

```
from datetime import datetime
import itertools
import math

starttime = datetime.now()
def permutationG(input, s):
    if len(s) == len(input): yield s
    for i in input:
        if i in s: continue
        s=s+i
        for x in permutationG(input, s): yield x
        s=s[:-1]
def op(operator, number1,number2):
    string=str(number1)+str(operator)+str(number2)
    return eval(string)

a=11
b=10
c=9
d=8
e=7
f=6

targetnumber = 101234
    
listofnumbers = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
listprep = ['+','-','*','/']
stringofnumbers = ''.join(str(e) for e in listofnumbers)


numberlocations =[]

for item in permutationG(listofnumbers,''):
    numberlocations.append(item)
numberlocations = set(numberlocations)

myarray = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(listprep, 5)
operatorlist = []
for item in myarray:
    #for all different numbers find the different permutations
    temp = list(itertools.permutations(item))
    operatorlist.extend(temp)
#remove duplicates
finaloplist = list(set(operatorlist))

dist=[math.inf]
currentclosestnumber = 0
count=0
looptime=datetime.now()
print('Starting Loop')

for item in numberlocations:
    for ops in finaloplist:
        initial_value = op(ops[0],item[0],item[1])
        for i in range(2,len(item)):
            intcheck2 = int(initial_value) - initial_value
            if initial_value != targetnumber and initial_value >= 0 and intcheck2 == 0:
                newvalue = op(ops[i-1], initial_value, item[i])
            else:
                break
            initial_value = newvalue
        attempt = initial_value
        intcheck = int(attempt) - attempt
        distance = targetnumber - initial_value
        if abs(distance) < abs(dist[0]) and intcheck == 0:
            currentclosestnumber = attempt
            dist[0]=distance
            print(attempt)
        if targetnumber == attempt:
            break
    if targetnumber == attempt:
        break

endtime = datetime.now()
stringtime= endtime-starttime
#print('Loops:    ', count)

if targetnumber == attempt:
    print('FOUNDIT!! Target Number = %s     Closest Number = %s        Time Elapsed = %s' %(targetnumber, currentclosestnumber, stringtime))
elif targetnumber!=attempt:
    print('Heres how close: Target Number = %s     Closest Number = %s        Time Elapsed = %s' %(targetnumber, currentclosestnumber, stringtime))
```

This outputs a time of roughly a minute and a half.

Another issue is because of the method I'm using (using eval string manipulation) I have no idea to show where the brackets go in the final formula when printed, or how to fit an eval into the zip at the end to show the numbers instead of the letters.

Any guidance is really appreciated.

---

Note: I have edited the post with the most recent version of the code. This reduced the time to calculate from 1:30 to 0:45. The major change was instead of one long string of calculations I created a for loop for each sequential operation, with an if statement to make sure that if the current value is negative or a decimal it breaks.

This reduces the number of calculations required significantly.

Comment: What *is* the "countdown number game"?

Comment: You get six numbers and you use them to reach a target, you can use as many or as few as you need.

Comment: "You get six numbers and you use them to reach a target". That means nothing. How do I 'use' a number? Addition? Multiplication? Subtraction? Division? Power? Sqrt? Log? Fourier Transform over a partial sequence of the numbers? What are the rules here?

Comment: Eliminating all strings and writing your own expression evaluator will definitely speed things up. There are less than a million possible expressions (assuming each number can only be used once), so the code should finish in a few seconds.

Comment: you can multiply, divide, add and times. Final answers must be integers. theres tones of working games online countdowns a tv show, this is just copying the concept

Comment: the issue i had was creating the evaluator and repeating it for all possible combinations of operators and number orders.

You dont have to use all 6 numbers btw

Comment: You have 6 numbers(`6!`) and 5 operators(each of which can take 4 values `4^5=1024`), so that's `737280` total possibilities. Each requiring up to 5 operations, should be able to find the answer in a few seconds

Comment: @Jay You forgot the 42 ways to correctly parenthesize the expression.  `(1-1)-1` is not `1-(1-1)`.  That changes expected time from seconds to minutes.

Comment: @btilly Ohh, the code doesn't seem to do that, thought that it was just doing BODMAS to get the unique expression, and that was one of the purposes of using eval in the code.

Comment: The code does include brackets, but not my placing them in the string to be evaluated. It creates a bracket round the two things its currently operating on, so for example if the order of operators was +,*,- it would go ((a+b)*c) - d. By changing the operators technically speaking all bracket combinations are also tried

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slower version but without the bugs.

I don't have time to try to optimize, but my thought is that most of the problem is in creating/destroying garbage in splitting subsets.

If I really wanted this to be fast, I think that you could use a dynamic programming approach.

```
def subset_splits (a_list):
    if 0 == len(a_list):
        yield ([], [])
    else:
        for sublist1, sublist2 in subset_splits(a_list[1:]):
            yield ([a_list[0]] + sublist1, sublist2)
            yield ([a_list[0]] + sublist2, sublist1)

def reachable (numbers):
    if 1 == len(numbers):
        yield (numbers[0], numbers[0])
    else:
        for list1, list2 in subset_splits(numbers):
            if 0 == len(list2):
                continue
            for x1, expr1 in reachable(list1):
                for x2, expr2 in reachable(list2):
                    yield x1+x2, (expr1, '+', expr2)
                    yield x1*x2, (expr1, '*', expr2)
                    yield x1-x2, (expr1, '-', expr2)
                    yield x2-x1, (expr2, '-', expr1)
                    if 0 != x2:
                        yield x1/x2, (expr1, '/', expr2)
                    if 0 != x1:
                        yield x2/x1, (expr2, '/', expr1)

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
target = 10000

best = numbers[0]
if best == target:
    print(("Answer: ", numbers[0], numbers[0]))
else:
    print(("Best: ", numbers[0], numbers[0]))
    done = False;
    for s, t in subset_splits(numbers):
        if done:
            break

        for x, expr in reachable(s):
            if x == target:
                print(("Answer: ", x, expr))
                done = True
                break
            elif abs(target-x) < abs(target-best):
                print(("Best: ", x, expr))
                best = x

        if done:
            break


        for x, expr in reachable(t):
            if x == target:
                print(("Answer: ", x, expr))
                done = True
                break
            elif abs(target-x) < abs(best-x):
                print(("Best: ", x, expr))
                best = x
```